# Sitecore query with two paths?

Tags: sitecore-query, rss

I'm configuring an RSS feed in Sitecore, and I'm using a query to select my items. I have a huge number of articles under `/sitecore/content/articles/issues` organized into folders by year (e.g. /2010, /2011, /2012...) The issue is that the RSS feed needs to include articles from 2019 AND 2020, but NOT from any of the other years. All of the articles are of the same template. Is it possible to use an OR statement in a fast query to choose path a OR path b?

This is my query currently :

```
query:/sitecore/content/Issues/2020//*[@@templateid='{DF4B07BF-922B-4CC0-9C1E-CFDC3750323C}']
```

...which obviously only gets articles from 2020, vs this, which gets articles from 2010-2020 :

```
query:/sitecore/content/Issues//*[@@templateid='{DF4B07BF-922B-4CC0-9C1E-CFDC3750323C}']
```

Ideally I need a way to do something like this :

```
query:/sitecore/content/Issues/2019//*[@@templateid='{DF4B07BF-922B-4CC0-9C1E-CFDC3750323C}'] OR /sitecore/content/Issues/2020//*[@@templateid='{DF4B07BF-922B-4CC0-9C1E-CFDC3750323C}']
```

Comment: IIRC fast queries are prefixed with "fast:". Technically this would be a Sitecore query not Sitecore Fast query. They have different limitations and capabilities.

Comment: I don't think you can have a query (or fast query) with two base paths. There is an old module on Sitecore Marketplace that modifies the RSS Feed functionality to use the Sitecore ContentSearch API instead of queries: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/ContentSearch_RSS_Feeds.aspx You might need to upgrade its source code to work with newer versions of Sitecore though.

Comment: What about a solution like this? https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorebetter/posts/filtered-rss-feed-using-the-sitecore-rules-engine

Comment: @MichaelWest you're right, this isn't a fast query. It turns the query supports two paths with a pipe: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/setting-up-rss-feeds.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query:/{path}/*` : Used to get all child items under the specified {path}.

So to get all the child items under 2019 and 2020 folder, we need to use pipe separator("|") to select multiple paths in one expression as follows.

```
query:/sitecore/content/Issues/2019/*|/sitecore/content/Issues/2020/*
```

Tested this in my local Sitecore instance. This is working fine.

**Reference & Credits :**

1. https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.html
2. http://rajsitecore.blogspot.com/2018/10/an-introduction-with-sitecore-query.html